# Excel VBA 2010: How to select all series items in an active chart?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-charts

I'm struggling with a compatibility issue with Excel 2010. The idea is to select all items in the chart first and then deselect those without a series name. Here's the code I have in 2016er version and it works perfectly.

```
For Each series In ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection
   series.IsFiltered = False
Next series

For Each series In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
   If series.Name = "" Then
      series.IsFiltered = True
   End If
Next series
```

However FullSeriesCollection doesn't work with Excel 2010. I tried SeriesCollection, but it doesn't select all items as wanted. What can I do to make it works in Excel 2010 either?

Comment: In 2010 you have to delete the series, you can't filter them.